# How to write new instance of subclass

Tags: java, swing, constructor, subclass, superclass

can somebody help me please properly extend my method USBtoUSART in Java?
I managed to extend it, but I have problem, to create a new instance of subclass.

```
public class USBtoUSART extends DesktopApplication1View implements SerialPortEventListener{
   public USBtoUSART(SingleFrameApplication app){
        super(app);    
   }
}


public class DesktopApplication1View extends FrameView {
    SingleFrameApplication ap;
    USBtoUSART serial = new USBtoUSART(ap);

    public DesktopApplication1View(SingleFrameApplication app) {      
        super(app);
    }
}
```

I wanted USBtoUSART to be a subclass of DesktopApplication1View, but I get error message of the app will crash. I think because the USBtoUSART serial = new USBtoUSART(ap); sequence.

Thanks for any help, it's eating me alive ...

Comment: Please post the error message or exception stack trace you receive.

Comment: `USBtoUSART` can't extend from `DesktopApplication1View` and be an instance variable within `DesktopApplication1View`

Comment: "I think because the USBtoUSART serial = new USBtoUSART(ap); sequence."

Remove the line and you'll be sure.

Comment: How can a parent use functionality from a child - You have a chicken and egg issue.  Until the parent is properly defined, the child can not be so you end up with the situation where neither the parent nor child can actually be defined as they now rely on each other

Comment: @MadProgrammer, sorry - I had an inheritance related brain fart. I realised the issue almost as soon as I had posted the comment.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'm glad I'm not the only one who has those ;)

Answer (score 0):

As @MadProgrammer already said: you cannot create a new object of a class that holds a subclass as a field and initializes it. This will create a `StackOverflowError` because of the circular dependency that you introduce.

Consider following example:

```
public class A {
    C c;
    B b = new B(c);

    public A(C c) {
        System.out.println("A constructor");
    }
} 

public class B extends A {
    public B(C c) {
        super(c);
    }
}

public class C {

}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A(new C());
//      new B(new C());
    }
}
```

Both the creation of a new `A` and a new `B` will return a `StackOverflowError` because they both will construct class `A` that creates an instance of class `B` that creates an instance of class `A`, etc.

Edit to use your example:

```
public class USBtoUSART extends DesktopApplication1View implements SerialPortEventListener{
   public USBtoUSART(SingleFrameApplication app){
        super(app);    
   }
}


public class DesktopApplication1View extends FrameView {
    SingleFrameApplication ap;

    public DesktopApplication1View(SingleFrameApplication app) {      
        super(app);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args){
 USBtoUSART serial = new USBtoUSART(new SingleFrameApplication());
}
```

This will happen:

1. Define `serial` as an object of `USBtoUSART`
2. Instantiate a new `USBtoUSART` object. This will perform the following actions:

   1. Enter the constructor of `USBtoUSART`
   2. Enter the constructor of its superclass, `DesktopApplication1View`
   3. Enter the constructor of its superclass, `FrameView`

Meanwhile, the parameter `SingleFrameApplication` will be passed to every constructor.

It sounds as if your general architecture setup is wrong. Do you perhaps want to extend `SingleFrameApplication`? You'll have to use a parameter in your constructor if you want `USBtoUSART` to be instantiated.

Alternatively, do something like this:

```
public class USBtoUSART extends DesktopApplication1View implements SerialPortEventListener{
       public USBtoUSART(){
            super(new SingleFrameApplication());    
       }
}

public static void Main(string[] args){
 USBtoUSART serial = new USBtoUSART();
}
```

But I don't know if this is applicable in your situation.

Comment: OK, I get it. So How I can can access DesktopApplication1View methods from USBtoUSART? Sorry, I am kind of newbie to Java.

Comment: @comeback: as long as the methods are declared `public` or `protected`, you can just use them as you would if it was the same class. Just create a new object of `USBtoUSART`, remove the circular dependency (`USBtoUSART serial = new USBtoUSART(ap);`) and you can use the methods.

Comment: OK, but I can't create a new object, because I have to use USBtoUSART serial = new USBtoUSART();. But the constructor of USBtoUSART has a parameter, I don't know how to use it, because it is SingleFrameApplication again.

Comment: @comeback: have you imported `SingleFrameApplication`? Are you sure it has a parameterless constructor?